# DynamoDb: Delete all items having same Hash Key

Tags: java, c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following table:

```
Table (documentId : Hash Key, userId: Range Key)
```

How can I write a code to delete all the items having the same `documentId` and preferably without retrieving the items.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Currently, You cannot delete all the items just by passing the Hash key, to delete an item it requires Hash + Range because that's what makes it unique.

```
You have to know both your (hash + range) to delete the item.
```

Edit: Here is the reference link from DynamoDB documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#API_DeleteItem_RequestSyntax

Please read the explanation of the "KEY" which clearly says that we must pass both Hash (Partition Key) and Range (Sort Key) to delete the item.

Comment: I will be very thankfull if you mention the reference

Comment: @Hans I have updated the answer, if you feel it is correct you can mark as answer.

Comment: This surprised me.  I'm more familiar with Cassandra, which has the option of deleting a whole partition by specifying just the partition key.

Comment: so is there anything DDB can do? I mean I cannot list all hashkeys in the table, I cannot delete all items for a given hash key (why does the sort key have to figure at all?!)... Completely unuseful api

Answer (score 15):

If you want to delete only by hash key, you need to query records first and then use `batchDelete` to delete all the records.

```
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
eav.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS(value));
DynamoDBQueryExpression<DocumentTable> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DocumentTable>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("documentId = :v1")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
List<DocumentTable> ddbResults = dynamoDBMapper.query(DocumentTable.class, queryExpression);
dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(ddbResults);
```

I would like to call out here that `deleteItem` deletes only one item at a time and both hash key and range key needs to be specified for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement where I need to delete more than 10 million of rows from DynamoDB table. I was hoping that there would be a way to delete all the items based on a specific partition key but unfortunately there is no way (atleast I couldn't find).

It's painful to specify the specific values of hashkey and sortKey. The only option is to scan the table to retrieve primary key (or composite key) and then iterate over it to delete a single item using deleteItem API.

You can delete upto **25 items ( as large as 400KB)** in a single call using `BatchWriteItem` API.

You can refer to this API from AWS for more information : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Comment: Why would you scan table? Simply get items via hash key first. Much better option than scan!

Comment: also have the issue, please update if you would have found anything better.