# Dynamo DB : Deleting entries within a table with HashKey + Range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, delete-operator

I have DynamoDB table with Hashkey + RangeKey. I am facing the following error while deleting an entry for a given HashKey and RangeKey.

Tried following approaches

1. Used a DynamoDBMapper to get the record (Obj) from DB using `DynamoDBQueryExpression` that includes both HashKey + RangeKey in KeyCondition. Performed `dynamoDBMapper.delete(Obj)`.
2. Referred to other post - [DynamoDb: Delete all items having same Hash Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259358/dynamodb-delete-all-items-having-same-hash-key) and tried

```java
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
eav.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS(value));
DynamoDBQueryExpression<DocumentTable> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DocumentTable>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("documentId = :v1")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
List<DocumentTable> ddbResults = dynamoDBMapper.query(DocumentTable.class, queryExpression);
dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(ddbResults);
```

In both the above cases I see the following exception

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: I12MUB0FSQNAQT6AH0RHE1B12JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

- Please help in case someone had similar issues.
- Is it not recommended to have a composite Key ( as HashKey and SortKey )?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to specify an item by giving a value for the key `documentId`. The error is trying to tell you that `documentId` isn't the name of the key in your table.

Replace `documentId` with the name of the key in you table.

Comment: Thank you. I found the fix. While I am not sure of the exact cause, this is what is the problem with my code
1. I am using Spring - org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
2. This enforced me to use @Id and I could not mark my `RangeKey` with appropriate annotation @DynamoDBRangeKey., there is another post which talks about this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738817/no-method-or-field-annotated-by-dynamodbhashkey-within-type-java-lang-string
*FIX*: Stopped using CrudRepository, this helped me to mark RangeKey correctly. Using dynamoDBMapper for DB operations